# why do I get Type mismatch: inferred type error. Looking to understand the reason

Tags: kotlin, object, generics, inheritance

I have following structure

```
open class Rule { open fun getRuleName(): String { return "DefaultRule" } }

class CustomRule: Rule() { override fun getRuleName(): String { return "CustomRule" } }

class Content<out T: Rule>(val rule: T)  
fun getDefaultRule(): Rule { return Rule() }

fun createDefaultContent(): Content<Rule> { return Content(rule = getDefaultRule()) }

fun createSpecialContent(): Content<CustomRule> { return Content(rule = CustomRule()) }

fun main() {
    var defaultRule = Rule()
    val customRule = CustomRule()
    defaultRule = CustomRule()   // passes as customRule is an extension of Rule
    var defaultRuleContent:Content<Rule> = createDefaultContent()
    val customRuleContent: Content<CustomRule> = createSpecialContent()
    // fails giving type mismatch error. // can someone provide some explanation around why exactly.
    // I know "Content<Rule>" is not a parent of "Content<CustomRule>"
    defaultRuleContent = customRuleContent
}
```

Can some one please explain the concept when dealing with generics assigning ?

I tried running the code. I have some understanding of the error. trying to get more detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

`GenericType<SomeSubtype>` is generally not a subtype or supertype of `GenericType<SomeSupertype>`, even if `SomeSubtype` is a subtype of `SomeSupertype`. In other generic type parameters are by default *invariant*.

Let's use `MutableList<T>` as an example, you cannot do:

```
val dogList = mutableListOf(Dog())
val animalList: MutableList<Animal> = dogList // you cannot do this
```

If you *could*, then this could happen:

```
// animalList refers to the same object as dogList, which is a list of dogs
// but we can now add a cat to it! Because we can add any Animal to MutableList<Animal>
animalList.add(Cat())
// now let's try getting the second item from the dog list
// but the second item is actually the cat that we just added!
val dog = dogList[1]
dog.bark() // the cat can't bark!
```

See the problem? This is why you are not allowed to assign `GenericType<SomeSubtype>` to `GenericType<SomeSupertype>` by default.

However, in your `Content` class, there isn't actually a method like `MutableList.add`, which is what allowed the aforementioned "craziness" to happen. The only property `rule` in `Content` is read-only and so it is safe to do the assignment.

This (`T` only occurs in an "output" position) means that it is possible to make `T` *covariant*, which makes `Content<SomeSubtype>` a subtype of `Content<SomeSupertype>`, and allows you to do the assignment.

If you just add `out`:

```
class Content<out T: Rule>(val rule: T)
//            ^^^
```

Then the assignment is valid, and this also prevents you from adding anything that involves `T` in an "input" position, like:

```
fun foo(rule: T) { /* ... */ }
```

Further reading: [Kotlin Generics Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance)